# How to improve this nginx rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I use this code to redirect a wordpress site from trailing slash vertion to non trailing slash verstion. For example from abc.com/en/ to redirect to abc.com/en

`if (!-d $request_filename) { rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent; }`

However, this code causes an unnecessary redirect to http first. So if I enter `https://www.example.com/en/`, it will first 301 to `http://www.example.com/en`, then 301 to https `https://www.example.com/en`. So how to improve this code to let it redirect directly to https version? And according to Nginx Pitfalls, using "if" is not recommended, can anyone please help to improve this code with a better version?

Thank you!

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ https://$host/$1 permanent;`

Comment: simple code, it works. Thanks!